# Comparing Nintex forms and flow to MS Flow/Power Apps Plan 2

Tags: flow, powerapp, nintex

My organization recently implemented O365 with an E5 license. As I have been learning about and have been working with MS Flow, Forms and PowerApps I have encountered some of the limitations that they have. In my research I came across Nintex as a powerful add on to the O365 and SharePoint online environment. At first glance it looks like Nintex is the answer to some of those limitations. However, it looks like the PowerApps Plan 2 (with it's inclusion of Flow Plan 2) is really on par with what Nintex forms & flow offers. Has anyone out there compared Microsoft's Plan 2 (and higher) offerings to Nintex's offerings?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick reminder that both nintex forms and InfoPath were specifically designed to turn paper forms into online forms, while PowerApps was specifically designed to create mobile apps using a variety of data sources. These are related goals, but different. If you need a form with 50 fields all on the same form, nintex and InfoPath were specifically designed for this scenario. However, I've never seen a mobile app with 50 fields on the same form, rather, mobile apps that need a lot of fields will have multiple forms with a few fields per form. If you need a form with 50 fields, along with conditional visibility rules, etc., the design experience in PowerApps is challenging, since it clearly wasn't designed for that purpose.

I'll let others address the licensing issue, but I would highly recommend looking into what kind of forms you need to build and what the design experience would be like for those scenarios, in addition to specific features provided by different licensing options.